# Questions in two columns (Exercise package)

Tags: exercises

How can I write questions and subquestions in multiple columns?
I would like to have these questions in two columns

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[margin=1.in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, exercise}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25} 
\parskip=10pt

\begin{document}

\begin{Exercise}[label=Ex1]
Simplify the following fractions.
\Question {$ \dfrac{t^2 - 16}{t^2 - 8t + 16} $}
\Question {$ \dfrac{2t^2 + 3t + 2}{t^2 - t - 2} $}
\Question {$ \dfrac{2t^2 - 4t - 6}{t^2 - 6t + 9} $}
\Question {$ \dfrac{2t^2 - t + -32}{4t^2 + 4t - 24} $}
\Question {$ \dfrac{7t^3 - 7t}{4t^3 + 2t^2 - 2t} $}
\end{Exercise}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation of `exercise`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/exercise/exercise.pdf), section 4, you can use

```
\begin{Exercise}
  ...
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \Question ...
    \Question ...
    \EndCurrentQuestion
  \end{multicols}
\end{Exercise}
```

to typeset questions in multiple columns. Note the `\EndCurrentQuestion` used before `\end{multicols}`.

A full example:

```
\documentclass{extarticle}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, exercise}
\usepackage{multicol}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}
\parskip=10pt


\begin{document}

\begin{Exercise}[label=Ex1]
  Simplify the following fractions.
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \Question {$ \dfrac{t^2 - 16}{t^2 - 8t + 16} $}
    \Question {$ \dfrac{2t^2 + 3t + 2}{t^2 - t - 2} $}
    \Question {$ \dfrac{2t^2 - 4t - 6}{t^2 - 6t + 9} $}
    \Question {$ \dfrac{2t^2 - t + -32}{4t^2 + 4t - 24} $}
    \Question {$ \dfrac{7t^3 - 7t}{4t^3 + 2t^2 - 2t} $}
    \EndCurrentQuestion
  \end{multicols}
\end{Exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]